# Explain why NSURL throws errors on nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

Most to all of the classes in Objective-C returns nil if passed nil or some error, but `NSURL` throws an exception. Specifically, the method `[NSURL fileURLWithPath]`.

It is documented:
*"Passing nil for this parameter produces an exception."*

But, can anyone explain Apple would throw an exception instead of returning nil?

Answer (score 1):

It is calling a method on `nil` that is allowed. Many methods can throw exceptions if given an invalid argument. For example see `NSMutableArray`'s `addObject:`.

Comment: addObject makes sense to throw an exception since that is a method on an existing object, and NSArray only contains objects so it can't add nil. But fileURLWithPath is an initializer.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky There's no hard and fast rule. It is perfectly reasonable to throw an exception as a way of preventing an untenable situation. A file URL based on a nonexistent path is untenable. Returning nil works well in cases where you are also passed an `error` by indirection, as the client expects to check the outcome, but returning a surprising nil is surprising and can cause problems down the road, as I'm sure you've experienced. NSDateFormatter `dateFromString:` is an interesting borderline case; it fails silently and returns nil, and I find that unfortunate.

Comment: "It is perfectly reasonable to throw an exception as a way of preventing an untenable situation." Indeed, it occurs to me to add that this is exactly what NSAssert is for - it's so that you can do this in your own code.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky - OK try `NSRegularExpression` and the class method `regularExpressionWithPattern:` passing in `nil` for the pattern. You are seeing a pattern which doesn't exist, which is why I thought you may have confused the issue with calling a method *on* a `nil` object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Apple's docs or error handling:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html

> exceptions are used solely for programmer errors